# Getting the footer written in css to disappear when viewed by a mobile device

Tags: html, css

I am having difficulty setting the page to adapt for view on a smart phone. I have tried the regular fixes of `display: none;` and and adding `.hidden` to what I need to go away. I have even tried combinations that should not work, but thought it was worth a go like footer `h4.hidden`. The xombined `.hidden` and `display: none;` and that worked on a couple of the sections that I need to go away, but the footer stubbornly stays. I have researched several sites, including this one, can not find an answer further than what I have.

I will include my css style page, the `home.htm` and a link to the site.

PS- This site is WONDERFUL and has helped me in so many ways!

```css
h1.hidden,

section.hidden,

footer h4.hidden {

  display: none;

}

body {

  background: rgb(99, 181, 237);

}

hgroup {

  background: rgb(151, 201, 151);

  -o-background-size: contain;

  -moz-background-size: contain;

  -webkit-background-size: contain;

  background-size: contain;

  height: 50px;

  width: 100%;

}

nav {

  width;

  100%;

}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {

  hgroup nav {

    font-size: 25px;

    color: rgb(0, 0, 255);

    margin: 15px;

    text-align: center;

  }

  nav li {

    display: block;

    background-image: url("arrow.png");

    background-position: right center;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    margin: 5px auto 5px auto;

    width: 60%;

    height: 50px;

    border: white solid 1px;

    -moz-border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;

    border-radius: 10px;

    -moz-box-shadow: inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5) 10px -5px 20px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5) 10px -5px 20px;

    box-shadow: inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5) 10px -5px 20px;

  }

  nav li:nth-child(odd) {

    background-color: rgb(224, 0, 0);

  }

  nav li:nth-child(even) {

    background-color: rgb(248, 0, 0);

  }

  nav li a {

    display: block;

    line-height: 50px;

    color: #98F5FF;

    text-align: center;

  }

  @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {

    /* Styles for Landscape screen */

  }

  nav {

    font-size: 25px;

    color: rgb(0, 0, 255);

    margin: 15px;

    text-align: center;

  }

  nav {

    display: block;

    background-image: url("arrow.png");

    background-position: right center;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    float: left;

    margin: 5px;

    width: 30%;

    height: 50px;

    border: white solid 1px;

    -moz-border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;

    border-radius: 10px;

    -moz-box-shadow: inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5) 10px -5px 20px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5) 10px -5px 20px;

    box-shadow: inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5) 10px -5px 20px;

  }

  nav li:nth-child(odd) {

    background-color: rgb(224, 0, 0);

  }

  nav li:nth-child(even) {

    background-color: rgb(248, 0, 0);

  }

  nav li a {

    display: block;

    line-height: 50px;

    color: #98F5FF;

    text-align: center;

  }

}
```

This is the HTML

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<title>Sealey Body Repair</title>
<script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
<link href="sealey_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 501px)" />
<link href="sealey_desktop.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 501px)" />
<link href="sealey_printmedia_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 501px)" />

<!-- Style sheet links for Internet Explorer prior to version 9 -->
<!-- [if 1t IE 9]>
  <link href="sealey_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
  <link href="sealey_desktop.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
   <![endif]-->

<link href="sealey_mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 500px)" />
<!--<link href="sealey.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 700px)" />-->


</head>

<body>

  <hgroup>
    <h1 align="center"><img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="Sealey Banner" /></h1>
    <!-- image obtained from Pixabay, free of copyrights under Creative Commons CC0 into the public domain.-->
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="sealey_home.htm">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="sealey_services.htm">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="sealey_about.htm">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="sealey_contact.htm">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="sealey_photos.htm">Photos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1 align="center">Welcome to Sealey Body Shop, Inc.</h1>
    <h2 align="center">The Best Auto Body Shop in Hastings</h2>
  </hgroup>

  <section>
    <p>Sealey Body Shop, Inc. is a family-owned business in Hastings Nebraska.</p>
  </section>

  <section id="reviews">
    <h2 align="left">Customer Reviews</h2>
    <blockquote>
      <p>"I'm very happy with the repair by Sealey! "&#8212;<cite>Rachael Broadwell</cite>
      </p>
      <p>"Great work! I really appreciate it. "&#8212;<cite>Hillary Broadwell</cite>
      </p>
      <p>"Fast, high quality, and a great price! "&#8212;<cite>Janelle Broadwell</cite>
      </p>
      <p>"Thanks so much! Best car repair shop in Hastings!! "&#8212;<cite>Rachael Broadwell</cite>
      </p>
    </blockquote>
  </section>

  <section align="left">
    <img src="images/sealey_lrg.jpg" alt="Sealey Shop Exterior" />
    <img src="images/plackard.jpg" alt="Sealey Plackard" />
    <img src="images/classiccarsresize2.jpg" alt="Classic Car Restoration" />
  </section>

  <br />
  <br />

  <footer>
    <h4 align="center"><address>Sealey Body Shop &bull; 201 S. Hastings Ave. &bull; Hastings, NE 68901 &bull; (402) 461-3244</address></h4>
    <h4 align="center"><img src="images/sealeylogo.png" alt="Sealey Logo" /></h4>
  </footer>

</body>
```

[A site being done in a class for a local area body shop](http://naturalattitude.org/sealey/sealey_home.htm)

Comment: You want to hide footer in mobile view?

Comment: Yes, for smart phones.  Another of my team sent a css stylesheet for tablets and it has the same issue.  I am wondering if the problem is with the HTML since I have tried all the suggested solutions and none have helped with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code into your CSS file.

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    footer {
      display:none;
    }
  }
```

In the following snippet, you can see your footer will disappear when the screen size is reduced to 500px.

```css
h1.hidden,

section.hidden,

footer h4.hidden {

  display: none;

}

body {

  background: rgb(99, 181, 237);

}

hgroup {

  background: rgb(151, 201, 151);

  -o-background-size: contain;

  -moz-background-size: contain;

  -webkit-background-size: contain;

  background-size: contain;

  height: 50px;

  width: 100%;

}

nav {

  width;

  100%;

}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {

  hgroup nav {

    font-size: 25px;

    color: rgb(0, 0, 255);

    margin: 15px;

    text-align: center;

  }

  nav li {

    display: block;

    background-image: url("arrow.png");

    background-position: right center;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    margin: 5px auto 5px auto;

    width: 60%;

    height: 50px;

    border: white solid 1px;

    -moz-border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;

    border-radius: 10px;

    -moz-box-shadow: inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5) 10px -5px 20px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5) 10px -5px 20px;

    box-shadow: inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5) 10px -5px 20px;

  }

  nav li:nth-child(odd) {

    background-color: rgb(224, 0, 0);

  }

  nav li:nth-child(even) {

    background-color: rgb(248, 0, 0);

  }

  nav li a {

    display: block;

    line-height: 50px;

    color: #98F5FF;

    text-align: center;

  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    footer {
      display:none;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {

    /* Styles for Landscape screen */

  }

  nav {

    font-size: 25px;

    color: rgb(0, 0, 255);

    margin: 15px;

    text-align: center;

  }

  nav {

    display: block;

    background-image: url("arrow.png");

    background-position: right center;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    float: left;

    margin: 5px;

    width: 30%;

    height: 50px;

    border: white solid 1px;

    -moz-border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;

    border-radius: 10px;

    -moz-box-shadow: inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5) 10px -5px 20px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5) 10px -5px 20px;

    box-shadow: inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5) 10px -5px 20px;

  }

  nav li:nth-child(odd) {

    background-color: rgb(224, 0, 0);

  }

  nav li:nth-child(even) {

    background-color: rgb(248, 0, 0);

  }

  nav li a {

    display: block;

    line-height: 50px;

    color: #98F5FF;

    text-align: center;

  }

}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a perfect solution to your question as mobile devices vary in size and functionality. Nonetheless, if you are okay with using JS, you can detect if the window of the browser has touch events, as most mobile devices do. This is I believe Modernizr's approach.

Here's the snippet you would need:

```
var hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window;

if (!hasTouch) {
    var root = document.documentElement;
    root.classList.add('no-touch');
}
```

Then in your css, have your footer set up as the following:

```
footer {
    display: none;
}

.no-touch footer {
    display: block;
}
```

#### Edit:

To account for screen size as well, the answer as others mention is media queries. Here is the two combined:

```
footer {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .no-touch footer {
         display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about tablet or iPad?

Comment: @APPinAIR Right. So the answer depends on whether the original poster prefers for the footer not to appear on touch devices or devices smaller than a certain dimension. Mobile devices can be categorized under both.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Oddly the footer remains strong and clearly present on the web page after trying these solutions. The other two section, h1 and section disappeared with the hidden keyword. I tried to place your solution in a few different positions, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Add media queries for the screen sizes you are targeting and use `display: none`.

Here is an example:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
   footer{
      display: none;
   }
}
```

For standard list of device screen sizes, [visit](http://here.https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Answer (score 0):

```
footer{
  @media screen and (min-width: 480px)
  display:none;
}
```

you  have to put in you CSS that you want the footer hidden in media

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Oddly the footer remains strong and clearly present on the web page after trying these solutions. The other two section, h1 and section disappeared with the hidden keyword. I tried to place your solution in a few different positions, but to no avail